# I don't understand the difference between firestore and storage and realtime database in firebase spark plan

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't understand the difference between firestore and storage and realtime database in the firebase spark plan.

I am creating an android application that requires around 10gb of storage and around 1000 realtime users downloading the file. Which cloud service should I use?

Answer (score 1):

well it depends on your needs
so for hosting files you should use **storage**  but the free plan gives you 5GB only and 50K/day downloads
the Firestore and realtime database are databases pretty much clear you use them to store information ( in files case you'd store the files URLs f.e ) you might not use them if your implementation doesn't require storing any data

you could use Firebase pay as you go plan it includes the free Spark quota too

---

**Edit**
here's where to find storage [image]

Comment: how do I use the storage I mean I only get the option of realtime and firestore?

Comment: @YashAgrawal on the left side menu there's firebase services 
Database tab contains Firestore and realtime only
right under it there's storage option  
I'll edit the answer and put an image where you find it, mark it as answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Either Realtime Database and Firestore are database.
Realtime database is JSON-based NoSQL data storage and Firestore is document-based data storage so you can keep user data in them.

If you want to store files that image, music, file or video etc.. should use Storage, not Firestore.

You can use Storage for files, Real-time database for user data.